# Not retrieving email and location from facebook - permissions are approved

Tags: android, facebook, performance, facebook-graph-api

Ok, so i am working on application which is implementing facebook login.

I followed login tutorial on facebook page, implementation is fine and working with my facebook account and few other accounts(i already published my app on google play), but not all.

Facebook approved my request for permissions, they are all live and my app is set to live.

Users receive null pointer exception when retrieving email or location and application crashes.

What i tried:

- checked for permissions inside oncomplete method, permissions are fine
- one of the users with crashes has email set to public, so this shouldnt be a problem

How to solve this problem, what should i check?

Here is my code:

```
 private final List<String> permissions;

 public LoginScreen() {
    permissions = Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email","user_location","user_birthday");
 }

    LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
    authButton.setReadPermissions(permissions);
    authButton.setFragment(this);

 private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state,
                                  Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        // Request user data and show the results
        if (mSession == null || isSessionChanged(session)) {
            mSession = session;

            Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                if (user != null) {
                    Log.v("gj1",Session.getActiveSession().getPermissions().toString());
                    Log.v("gj1","stateopen");
                    name=user.getFirstName();
                    surname=user.getLastName();
                    Object objEmail=user.getProperty("email");
                    if(objEmail!=null)
                    {
                        mail=user.getProperty("email").toString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Object objCmail=user.getProperty("contact_email");
                        if(objCmail!=null)
                        {
                            mail=user.getProperty("contact_email").toString();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            mail="null@mail.com";
                        }

                    }
                    gender=user.getProperty("gender").toString();
                    city="N/A";
                    username=name+surname+user.getId();
                    password=user.getId();
                    if(gender.equals("male"))
                    {
                        interested="F";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        interested="M";
                    }


                    if(user.getProperty("birthday")!=null) {
                        String dateFromDB = user.getProperty("birthday").toString();
                        username=name+surname+user.getProperty("birthday");
                        SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
                        try {
                            Date yourDate = parser.parse(dateFromDB);
                            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                            calendar.setTime(yourDate);
                            Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
                            age = now.get(Calendar.YEAR) - calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                        } catch (ParseException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        age=0;
                    }

                    GraphPlace userLocation = user.getLocation();
                    city = (userLocation != null)? userLocation.toString() : "N/A";

                    }
                }
            }
        }).executeAsync();
        }
    } else if (state.isClosed()) {

    }
}
```

Error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method          'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
at   com.apps.medico.location_matchup.LoginScreen$5.onCompleted(LoginScreen.java:339)
at com.facebook.Request$1.onCompleted(Request.java:281)
at com.facebook.Request$4.run(Request.java:1666)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
```

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)

Should i provide more code?

Comment: It would help to post logcat if you can repro the error in your environment

Comment: I added logcat code, this error is before i wrapped problematical code with if

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several possibilities of your code not getting an email for the user, including, but not limited to:

- The user did not give you email permissions (they can x-out the permission during the auth flow, or they can remove that permission from the Facebook website or app at a later time)
- The user might not have a valid email address (there are ways to sign up for Facebook without providing or verifying an email)

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user for more info.

Comment: Ok, I didnt know that before, i solved my problem with catching null objects! Thank you for clarification :)